Could not find Angular Material core theme angular 18
I am new to angular 18 and I am trying to use the angular material for a simple application development.
When I am adding the @angular/material with theme as azure-blue I am facing below challenges

Even though CLI output says it updated the styles.scss, I don't see any traces or updates happening in the styles.scss file
When I tried setting up the custom theme (due to the above point), I am receiving below warning/error in the browser dev-tools console.

Could not find Angular Material core theme. Most Material components may not work as expected. For more info refer to the theming guide: https://material.angular.io/guide/theming
I tried following the steps provided in the angular material official documentation
Angular Material Theming Guide
Additionally I also tried adding @import "../node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css"; to my styles.scss file and tried updating the path in angular.json but no luck so far
Can anyone please help me getting rid of these problems and setting up the angular material theme.

There has been an issue with placing the M3-loaded marker in version 18.0.0 of Angular Material Components. The issue has been resolved in version 18.0.1 of of the library. You can find the corresponding issue, release log and the corresponding fix on GitHub.
Try to update @angular/material to version 18.0.1 to resolve your problem.

Thanks @UnlikePluto. This seems to have worked well. But, I still see an issue with toolbar color. Any chance you can help on the same ?

Did you found a solution? I updated material to 18.0.1, and I still see the warning when adding material to the project and the toolbar has no background color.

Yes, you can refer to the following SO question https://stackoverflow.com/q/78535414/9647266. You can follow the M2 approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78555393/9647266, or the M3 approach for theming: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78535441/9647266

I tried the exact steps, these are the things I noticed.
The installer doesn't modify the styles.scss, instead it adds the default style to angular.json:
...
"styles": [
          "@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/azure-blue.css",
          "src/styles.scss"
        ],
        ...

After this, including the default buttons html and ts, as shown below. There's a working Stackblitz demo below.
Ts:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatDividerModule } from '@angular/material/divider';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [MatButtonModule, MatDividerModule, MatIconModule],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.scss',
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'test';
}

Html:
<section>
  <div class="example-label">Basic</div>
  <div class="example-button-row">
    <button mat-button>Basic</button>
    <button mat-button color="primary">Primary</button>
    <button mat-button color="accent">Accent</button>
    <button mat-button color="warn">Warn</button>
    <button mat-button disabled>Disabled</button>
    <a mat-button href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank">Link</a>
  </div>
</section>
<mat-divider></mat-divider>
<section>
  <div class="example-label">Raised</div>
  <div class="example-button-row">
    <button mat-raised-button>Basic</button>
    <button mat-raised-button color="primary">Primary</button>
    <button mat-raised-button color="accent">Accent</button>
    <button mat-raised-button color="warn">Warn</button>
    <button mat-raised-button disabled>Disabled</button>
    <a mat-raised-button href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank">Link</a>
  </div>
</section>
<mat-divider></mat-divider>
<section>
  <div class="example-label">Stroked</div>
  <div class="example-button-row">
    <button mat-stroked-button>Basic</button>
    <button mat-stroked-button color="primary">Primary</button>
    <button mat-stroked-button color="accent">Accent</button>
    <button mat-stroked-button color="warn">Warn</button>
    <button mat-stroked-button disabled>Disabled</button>
    <a mat-stroked-button href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank"
      >Link</a
    >
  </div>
</section>
<mat-divider></mat-divider>
<section>
  <div class="example-label">Flat</div>
  <div class="example-button-row">
    <button mat-flat-button>Basic</button>
    <button mat-flat-button color="primary">Primary</button>
    <button mat-flat-button color="accent">Accent</button>
    <button mat-flat-button color="warn">Warn</button>
    <button mat-flat-button disabled>Disabled</button>
    <a mat-flat-button href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank">Link</a>
  </div>
</section>
<mat-divider></mat-divider>
<section>
  <div class="example-label">Icon</div>
  <div class="example-button-row">
    <div class="example-flex-container">
      <button
        mat-icon-button
        aria-label="Example icon button with a vertical three dot icon"
      >
        <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
      </button>
      <button
        mat-icon-button
        color="primary"
        aria-label="Example icon button with a home icon"
      >
        <mat-icon>home</mat-icon>
      </button>
      <button
        mat-icon-button
        color="accent"
        aria-label="Example icon button with a menu icon"
      >
        <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
      </button>
      <button
        mat-icon-button
        color="warn"
        aria-label="Example icon button with a heart icon"
      >
        <mat-icon>favorite</mat-icon>
      </button>
      <button
        mat-icon-button
        disabled
        aria-label="Example icon button with a open in new tab icon"
      >
        <mat-icon>open_in_new</mat-icon>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<mat-divider></mat-divider>
<section>
  <div class="example-label">FAB</div>
  <div class="example-button-row">
    <div class="example-flex-container">
      <div class="example-button-container">
        <button
          mat-fab
          color="primary"
          aria-label="Example icon button with a delete icon"
        >
          <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="example-button-container">
        <button
          mat-fab
          color="accent"
          aria-label="Example icon button with a bookmark icon"
        >
          <mat-icon>bookmark</mat-icon>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="example-button-container">
        <button
          mat-fab
          color="warn"
          aria-label="Example icon button with a home icon"
        >
          <mat-icon>home</mat-icon>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="example-button-container">
        <button
          mat-fab
          disabled
          aria-label="Example icon button with a heart icon"
        >
          <mat-icon>favorite</mat-icon>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<mat-divider></mat-divider>
<section>
  <div class="example-label">Mini FAB</div>
  <div class="example-button-row">
    <div class="example-flex-container">
      <div class="example-button-container">
        <button
          mat-mini-fab
          color="primary"
          aria-label="Example icon button with a menu icon"
        >
          <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="example-button-container">
        <button
          mat-mini-fab
          color="accent"
          aria-label="Example icon button with a plus one icon"
        >
          <mat-icon>plus_one</mat-icon>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="example-button-container">
        <button
          mat-mini-fab
          color="warn"
          aria-label="Example icon button with a filter list icon"
        >
          <mat-icon>filter_list</mat-icon>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="example-button-container">
        <button
          mat-mini-fab
          disabled
          aria-label="Example icon button with a home icon"
        >
          <mat-icon>home</mat-icon>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>


Stackblitz has some problem running; download the project and run it.
Stackblitz -> cd test -> npm i && npm run start

Thanks @Naren Murali for your reply however, I still see the warning/error in the dev tools, Additionally,when I tried adding the toolbar and tried giving it color='primary' it shows no changes on the browser. am I missing anything here ?

@DhyeyDave share github repo? or restart code editor? compare your code with the stackblitz to find what is wrong!

Please find the github repo link below https://github.com/Raghu0701/angular-material-18-test
I tried restarting code editor multiple times, tried creating the project multiple times but no luck

@DhyeyDave The code ran in my local with no issues, maybe try upgrading angular cli npm i @angular/cli@latest and npm i @angular/core@latest, then try upgrading node to the angular 18 compatible version

So you are saying you are able to see the background color in UI in toolbar ?

@DhyeyDave there is no toolbar in the github repo, please check app.com.html

Thanks for looking at the github repo @Naren Murali I see the mat-toolbar at this path test/src/app/app.component.html inside the main branch of the repo. Can you please confirm if we are checking at the same place.
